# PHP Count words in array

Tags: php, arrays, counting

Ok, so in my case i have an array kinda like this (but MUCH larger)

```
$array = [
    0 => "TOD",
    1 => "TOD",
    2 => "MAX",
    3 => "JEFF",
    4 => "TOD",
    5 => "MAX",
    6 => "JEFF",
    7 => "MAX",
    8 => "MAX"
];
```

Now my question is, is there a way to count how many occurences of `TOD`,`JEFF` & `MAX`there are in the array `$array` and then store them into seperate variables, so for example desired outcome would be for there to be 3 seperate variables with these as there values (based off of the sample code shown above)

```
$todAmount = 3;
$jeffAmount = 2;
$maxAmount = 4;
```

I've done quite a bit of research and havn't really found out a good way to do this :/

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_count_values()` is probably what you need.

```
<?php

$array = [
    0 => "TOD",
    1 => "TOD",
    2 => "MAX",
    3 => "JEFF",
    4 => "TOD",
    5 => "MAX",
    6 => "JEF",
    7 => "MAX",
    8 => "MAX"
];
    print_r(array_count_values($array));
?>
```

Comment: Thanks it works great :)

Answer (score 0):

That should help you...

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

try

```
print_r(array_count_values($array));
```

Comment: Thanks it works perfect :)